# If $\phi$ and $\sigma$ are solutions of the ODE then $\phi(t)=\sigma(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n$, $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a continuos function. Suppose that for all $(t_0,x_0) \in \Omega$ there exists unique local solution $x:I_{t_0,x_0}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ of

\begin{equation*}
x'=f(t,x) \quad x(t_0)=x_0
\end{equation*}

Prove that if $\phi:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\sigma:J\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ are solutions of the ODE $x'=f(t,x)$ such that $\phi$ and $\sigma$ have a coincide point, then $\phi(t)=\sigma(t)$ for all $t\in I\cap J$.

Can somebody give a hint of what I have to do in this problem.

Comment: Hi! @CharlesXavier. Maybe can you show your attempts?

Comment: @Ramanujan I feel bad and useless for saying this but  I don't know how to start.

Comment: If two solutions are equal at a point, then they must be equal "locally" i.e. in a neighbourhood of that point, by uniqueness. Do you understand this statement? (Also, I think $I,J$ have to be connected.)

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Teresa, I have no more information about $I$ and $J$, sorry. About the statement you mentioned, can you explain it a little more, I'm beginning in the theory of ODE. Sorry for my bad english, i haven't taken many classes.

Comment: @CharlesXavier I get the problems you're facing. See, " there exists unique local solution" means that if you have the ODE and a value at a point, then around that point, in some neighbourhood there's exactly one solution of that ODE. Imagine now, that you gave me two solutions to this ODE, that were the same at some point (a coincide point). Then, they are the same in a neighbourhood of that point as well. Is that clear to you? From here the proof involves an open sets/connectedness trick, which I will explain once you get here.

Comment: Also, please let me know your native language, so if there are words that you don't understand in my explanations, then I will Google Translate those words for you.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Now I understand your explanation. And don't worry about my understanding of english language, my writing and speaking abilities are just something I need to improve.  Now, can you explain to me the "open sets/ connectedness" trick. Now I know that  if $\phi: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\sigma: J \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ are solutions of the IVP $x'=f(t,x)$, $x(t_0)=x_0$ such that have a coincidence point $t_0\in I\cap J$ and this IVP has a local solution, then $\phi(B_{t_0}(r))=\sigma(B_{t_0}(r))$ for some $r>0$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. Now, the open sets and connectedness argument works like this : suppose that $S = \{t : \phi(t) = \sigma(t)\}$. We know that $S$ is non-empty. We can prove that $S$ is open , by this "local uniqueness". Also, $S$ is closed, because it is the set where two continuous functions are equal. Therefore, $S$ is open and closed. For example, if $I \cap J$ is connected, then it shows that $S = I \cap J$, because a connected set can't have a non-empty subset which is both open and closed. Therefore the soutions coincide everywhere. However, note that without connectedness,...

Comment: ... the result is in fact false. I will give a counterexample once you've understood this argument above.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Now I get it, Teresa!. Thank you so much!!!!!!

Comment: To prove it is closed, I chose a convergent sequence $t_n \in S$ with limit $t^*$ and since $\phi$ and $\sigma$ are solutions, then they are continuos functions and beacuse of that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \phi(t_n)=\phi(t^*)$ and the same for $\sigma$ and $\phi(t^*)=\sigma(t^*)$. Now each convergence sequecen in $S$ has limit on $S$ so $S$ is closed.

Comment: To prove $S$ is open, I consider the Cauchy problem on $S$ $x'=f(t,x)$ with $x(\overline{t})=\overline{x}$. And thanks to your comment, $\phi$ and $\sigma$ are solutions to this IVP and this solution is unique by hypotesis.  So $\phi$ and $\sigma$ coincide in a neighborhood  of $\overline{t}$, and then doing this for all $t\in S$ results that $S$ is the union of open balls, then $S$ is open. So $S=I\cap J$

Comment: @CharlesXavier You have got it very well!+1. Now, we need to write an answer on this one.